# The difference in meaning between "I would…if I could" and "I will…if I can"

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I would go on vacation if I could get the time off (use in the past)?
I will go on vacation if I can get the time off (use in future and present)?

Comment: Do you know the difference between real and unreal grammar? How about the so-called "first conditional" and "second conditional"? If not, look those up first